# Animating two objects to the same spot but one is lower

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm attempting to animate two objects that start in the same position to the same spot at the end. However even though on my page it says they have the same `top` value, they are not in the same spot.

Also for the sake of clarity I need to use the same `position` attributes as in the demo, I know it would be easier with `position: absolute;` but it is not an option for my current project.

```js
$('#backdrop').click(function() {
  var sqT = $('#sq-green').offset().top - 100;

  $('#sq-green, #sq-blue').animate({
    'top': -sqT
  })
})
```

```css
#backdrop {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#sq-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.sq {
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
  position: relative;
}
#sq-green {
  background: green;
  top: 4em;
}
#sq-blue {
  background: #337ab7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="backdrop">
        <div id="sq-container">
          <div class="sq" id="sq-green">
          </div>
          <div class="sq" id="sq-blue">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ys52yru8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally both the elements are present at the same position because of the `top` value that is given for the green element using CSS. If this setting is not present, they will be one below the other.

```
#sq-green {
    background: green;
    top: 4em; /* this is the reason why they are present in same position */
}
```

The `top` value of 4em is equal to the height of the green element and so it is pushed below by its own height and thus ends up being in the same position as the blue element.

If after the animation also they need to be in the same position, then you need to get the `height` of the green element and add it to the calculated value.

```
$('#backdrop').click(function() {
  var sqT = $('#sq-green').offset().top - 100;
  var height = $('#sq-green').height();
  $('#sq-green').animate({
    'top': -sqT + height
  });
  $('#sq-blue').animate({
    'top': -sqT
  });
})
```

```js
$('#backdrop').click(function() {
  var sqT = $('#sq-green').offset().top - 100;
  var height = $('#sq-green').height();
  $('#sq-green').animate({
    'top': -sqT + height
  });
  $('#sq-blue').animate({
    'top': -sqT
  });
})
```

```css
#backdrop {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#sq-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.sq {
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
  position: relative;
}
#sq-green {
  background: green;
  top: 4em;
}
#sq-blue {
  background: #337ab7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="backdrop">
        <div id="sq-container">
          <div class="sq" id="sq-green">
          </div>
          <div class="sq" id="sq-blue">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```